# Finding largest difference in array of compass headings

Tags: algorithm, math, distance

I'm trying to have the "range" of compass headings over the last X seconds. Example: Over the last minute, my heading has been between 120deg and 140deg on the compass. Easy enough right? I have an array with the compass headings over the time period, say 1 reading every second.

```
[ 125, 122, 120, 125, 130, 139, 140, 138 ]
```

I can take the **minimum and maximum** values and there you go. My range is **from 120 to 140.**

Except it's not that simple. Take for example if my heading has shifted from 10 degrees, to 350 degrees (ie it "passed" through North, changing -20deg.

Now my array might look something like this:

```
[ 9, 10, 6, 3, 358, 355, 350, 353 ]
```

Now the Min is **3 and max 358**, which is not what I need :( I'm looking for the most "right hand" (clockwise) value, and most "left hand" (counter-clockwise) value.

Only way I can think of, is finding the largest arc along the circle that includes none of the values in my array, but I don't even know how I would do that.

Would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Does `Diff = Abs(A - B); if (Diff >= 180) Diff = 360 - Diff;` correction solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem Analysis

To summarize the problem, it sounds like you want to find both of the following:

1. The two readings that are closest together (for simplicity: in a clockwise direction) AND
2. Contain all of the other readings between them.

So in your second example, 9 and 10 are only 1° apart, but they do not contain all the other readings.  Conversely, traveling clockwise from 10 to 9 would contain all of the other readings, but they are 359° apart in that direction, so they are not closest.

In this case, I'm not sure if using the minimum and maximum readings will help.  Instead, I'd recommend sorting all of the readings.  Then you can more easily check the two criteria specified above.

Here's the second example you provided, sorted in ascending order:

`[ 3, 6, 9, 10, 350, 353, 355, 358 ]`

If we start from the beginning, we know that traveling from reading 3 to reading 358 will encompass all of the other readings, but they are `358 - 3 = 355°` apart.  We can continue scanning the results progressively.  Note that once we circle around, we have to add 360 to properly calculate the degrees of separation.

```
[ 3, 6, 9, 10, 350, 353, 355, 358 ]
  *-------------------------->               358 -   3 = 355° separation

[ 3, 6, 9, 10, 350, 353, 355, 358 ]
->   *-----------------------------  (360 +   3) -   6 = 357° separation

[ 3, 6, 9, 10, 350, 353, 355, 358 ]
---->   *--------------------------  (360 +   6) -   9 = 357° separation

[ 3, 6, 9, 10, 350, 353, 355, 358 ]
------->   *-----------------------  (360 +   9) -  10 = 359° separation

[ 3, 6, 9, 10, 350, 353, 355, 358 ]
---------->    *-------------------  (360 +  10) - 350 =  20° separation

[ 3, 6, 9, 10, 350, 353, 355, 358 ]
-------------->     *--------------  (360 + 350) - 353 = 357° separation

[ 3, 6, 9, 10, 350, 353, 355, 358 ]
------------------->     *---------  (360 + 353) - 355 = 358° separation

[ 3, 6, 9, 10, 350, 353, 355, 358 ]
------------------------>     *----  (360 + 355) - 358 = 357° separation
```

## Pseudocode Solution

Here's a pseudocode algorithm for determining the minimum degree range of reading values.  There are definitely ways it could be optimized if performance is a concern.

```
// Somehow, we need to get our reading data into the program, sorted
// in ascending order.
// If readings are always whole numbers, you can use an int[] array
// instead of a double[] array.  If we use an int[] array here, change
// the "minimumInclusiveReadingRange" variable below to be an int too.
double[] readings = populateAndSortReadingsArray();

if (readings.length == 0)
{
  // Handle case where no readings are provided.  Show a warning,
  // throw an error, or whatever the requirement is.
}
else
{

  // We want to track the endpoints of the smallest inclusive range.
  // These values will be overwritten each time a better range is found.
  int minimumInclusiveEndpointIndex1;
  int minimumInclusiveEndpointIndex2;
  double minimumInclusiveReadingRange;  // This is convenient, but not necessary.
                                        // We could determine it using the
                                        // endpoint indices instead.

  // Check the range of the greatest and least readings first.  Since
  // the readings are sorted, the greatest reading is the last element.
  // The least reading is the first element.
  minimumInclusiveReadingRange = readings[array.length - 1] - readings[0];
  minimumInclusiveEndpointIndex1 = 0;
  minimumInclusiveEndpointIndex2 = array.length - 1;

  // Potential to skip some processing.  If the ends are 180 or less
  // degrees apart, they represent the minimum inclusive reading range.
  // The for loop below could be skipped.

  for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
  {
    if ((360.0 + readings[i-1]) - readings[i] < minimumInclusiveReadingRange)
    {
      minimumInclusiveReadingRange = (360.0 + readings[i-1]) - readings[i];
      minimumInclusiveEndpointIndex1 = i;
      minimumInclusiveEndpointIndex2 = i - 1;
    }
  }

  // Most likely, there will be some different readings, but there is an
  // edge case of all readings being the same:
  if (minimumInclusiveReadingRange == 0.0)
  {
    print("All readings were the same: " + readings[0]);
  }
  else
  {
    print("The range of compass readings was: " + minimumInclusiveReadingRange +
          " spanning from " + readings[minimumInclusiveEndpointIndex1] +
          " to " + readings[minimumInclusiveEndpointIndex2]);
  }

}
```

There is one additional edge case that this pseudocode algorithm does not cover, and that is the case where there are multiple minimum inclusive ranges...

- Example 1: [0, 90, 180, 270] which has a range of 270 (90 to 0/360, 180 to 90, 270 to 180, and 0 to 270).
- Example 2: [85, 95, 265, 275] which has a range of 190 (85 to 275 and 265 to 95)

If it's necessary to report each possible pair of endpoints that create the minimum inclusive range, this edge case would increase the complexity of the logic a bit.  If all that matters is determining the value of the minimum inclusive range or it is sufficient to report just one pair that represents the minimum inclusive range, the provided algorithm should suffice.